# How to calculate civil twilight timings?

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

I am writing a program that requires calculations of civil twilight timings. I know how to calculate sunrise and sunset timings(actually I just searched online for a formula and copied it into my code blindly), but I can't find any resources on twilight timings. Everything I know about this is that when the sun elevation is from 0 to -6 degrees, it's civil twilight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per as my knowledge, for Hour angle calculation you are using Zenith distance as 90.833 degrees, just replace 90.833 with 96 degrees(Civil twilight), 102 (Nautical) and 108 (astronomical)[image]